# Vulkan Storage Buffers, loss of data

Tags: vulkan, compute-shader

I have been passing glm::vec3's in an array to a storage buffer to be processed by a compute shader, but once it has been modified I am getting some malformed data back.

Shader

```
#version 450

#extension GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects : enable

layout(binding = 0) buffer DataObject {
    vec3[] floatArray;
} data;

void main()
{
    data.floatArray[gl_GlobalInvocationID.x].x = 45.0123f;
    data.floatArray[gl_GlobalInvocationID.x].y = 45.0123f;
    data.floatArray[gl_GlobalInvocationID.x].z = 45.0123f;
}
```

Data being passed

```
struct DataObject
{
    glm::vec3 payload[2];
};

...

Buffer payload_buffer;
VkDeviceSize buffer_size = sizeof(DataObject);
CreateBuffer(engine, buffer_size, VK_BUFFER_USAGE_STORAGE_BUFFER_BIT, VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT | VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_COHERENT_BIT, payload_buffer);


// Create the data that will be saved
DataObject payload;

// Move the data to the GPU
memcpy(payload_buffer.mapped_memory, &payload, (::size_t)buffer_size);
```

The data that is returned is as follows

```
v1 x:45.0123f y:45.0123f z:45.0123f
v2 x:0 y:45.0123f z:45.0123f
```

Has anyone else come across this issue? and if so how would i resolve it?

Comment: It could be any number of things. It could have to do with synchronization, something that `CreateBuffer` is doing wrong, what your compute shader is doing, or many other things. There's no way we can diagnose your problem from this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's alignment. `Vec3`s in storage buffers must be aligned to 16 bytes (same as `vec4`).

replace DataObject with:

```
struct DataObject
{
    glm::vec4 payload[2];
};
```

Comment: That worked great thanks. If there a reference doc or something that shows the different data types that can and can't be passed to the storage buffer in this way?

Comment: @0xen to be exact the default layout picked for buffer is std430 which aligns vec3 to 16 bytes.